# Sql distinct selective row after a join question

Tags: sql, join, distinct

Let's say i have 2 tables Customer and Books.

Table Books can have multiple rows that pertain to a row in Customer.

Ex:
customer John Doe has an id of 1000.
Table Books has 2 rows with a member_id column with 1000 (John Doe).

These 2 rows are identical EXCEPT one of the fields (book title) is empty. The other row has a value for a title.

Question:
How can i query this so that I retrieve the row with the valid title value, BUT, if both title values are empty, then it just returns a single row?

I certainly hope that made sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use a distinct operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.member_id, Books.book_title
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Books ON Customers.member_id = Books.member_id
```

If that does not work correctly you could use an inner select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (SELECT Customers.member_id, Books.book_title
      FROM Customers
      INNER JOIN Books ON Customers.member_id = Books.member_id) As newTable
```

Also, if this is a frequently used query I would avoid a UNION because they are known to have performance problems.

**In response to the edit:**

```
SELECT Customers.member_id, Customer_Info.Name, ISNULL(newTable.book_title, '')
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Customer_Info
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT member_id, book_title FROM Books) newTable
    ON newTable.member_ID = Customers.member_id
```

This should return all books associated with a customer (but only one time for each title and if no books are found then it will return an empty string.)  If this does not answer the question please include some additional information about the tables and an example of the result you would like and I will update.

**OK, now I think I know what you are looking for:**

Here is a possible query based on your original question using the tables provided.  However, it will not work if the customer has two distinct e-mail addresses set; in that case, you could add a TOP(1) to ensure only one result but you won't know if it is the "right result."

```
SELECT Customers.member_id, Office.Office_Name, ISNULL(newTable.email, '')
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Office
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT member_id, email 
           FROM Books 
           WHERE email IS NOT NULL AND email <> '') newTable
    ON newTable.member_ID = Customers.member_id
```

Here is another query based on the data you provided and the example output.

```
SELECT Member_Name, Email
FROM thridTable
WHERE Member_Name = @SomeInputParameter
```

I'm not sure how representative your sample data is but why would you be storing the member name in more than one table?  That is a guaranteed headache in the future.

Comment: ok, allow me to throw in this wrench.
The reason why i cant do a distinct is that there are 3 tables.
The 3rd table being CutomerInfo.

So there are two JOINS (Customer-CustomerInfo, and Customer-Books).
The rows returned contains fields from Customer, CustomerInfo, and Books.

I can get to the point of returning either all Books or a book with a title (where book.title <> ''). Perhaps i need to check if the first query returns something, and if it doesnt then do a second query with the (where book.title <> '') removed?

Comment: thanks jellmonk.
Im having to tweak your new response snippet as its complaining about member_id (on the last line). Im massaging it around. If it works, ill let you know. If it doesnt, ill provide tables.

Comment: seems like its not working because....

LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT member_id, book_title FROM Books) newTable

doesn't return a single row, it still returns multiple rows (since the book_title differs per row).

Comment: BUT this still doesnt work for Bryce since he doesnt have any email defined.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying, this query will return all records with a non-null book title plus all customer records that have no valid book records, valid being defined as a book record with a non-null title.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, b.title
FROM customer c
JOIN book b ON c.id = b.customer_id
WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT c.id, c.name, NULL
FROM customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT title FROM book b WHERE customer_id = c.id AND title IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
isnull(BOOKTITLE,'') = ''
```

on that field and a distinct, and it should give one result